# eigenvalues of symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose we have $n \times n$ symmetric matrix $A$ with all diagonal entries zero and remaining entries are non negative. Let $B$ be the matrix obtained from $A$ by deleting its $k$th row and $k$th column and remaining entries of $B$ are less equal the corresponding entries of $A$. Then the largest eigenvalue of $B$ is less equal the largest eigenvalue of $A$ and the smallest eigenvalue of $A$ is less equal the smallest eigenvalue of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

It is a standard result in the theory of non-negative matrices:

> If $A,B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are such that $0\leq|B|\leq A$, then $\rho(B)\leq\rho(A)$.

See, e.g., Theorem 2.21 in [Varga's book](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Matrix_Iterative_Analysis.html?id=ix__1MNMHfIC&redir_esc=y).

Just plug in your $A$ and $B$.